# No such file or directory while trying to execute a 64-bit executable (No related to lsb-core issue which is resolved)

Tags: 14.04

```
$ file <Binary name>
<Binary name>: ELF 64-bit LSB executable, x86-64, version 1 (GNU/Linux), dynamically linked (uses shared libs), for GNU/Linux 2.6.32, BuildID[sha1]=ad67346bbf303b266c2f08abfb31c9ecfa541cd1, not stripped
```

---

```
$ arch
x86_64
```

---

```
$ uname -a 
Linux psa1-DL-H61S 4.4.0-75-generic #96~14.04.1-Ubuntu SMP Thu Apr 20 11:06:30 UTC 2017 x86_64 x86_64 x86_64 GNU/Linux
```

---

```
$ uname -m
x86_64
```

---

```
$ ldd <Binary name>
    linux-vdso.so.1 =>  (0x00007fffdade1000)
    libboost_system.so.1.58.0 => /home/lib/libboost_system.so.1.58.0 (0x00007f1126abc000)
    libCommonAPI.so.3 => /home/lib/libCommonAPI.so.3 (0x00007f112689c000)
    libCommonAPI-DBus.so.3 => /home/lib/libCommonAPI-DBus.so.3 (0x00007f1126594000)
    libjsoncpp.so.0.10.4 => /home/lib/libjsoncpp.so.0.10.4 (0x00007f112635d000)
    libpersistence_client_library.so => /home/lib/libpersistence_client_library.so (0x00007f1126138000)
    libpthread.so.0 => /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libpthread.so.0 (0x00007f1125efe000)
    libdlt.so.2 => /home/lib/libdlt.so.2 (0x00007f1125cda000)
    libbtcore.so => /home/libbtcore.so (0x00007f11259a8000)
    libstdc++.so.6 => /home/lib/libstdc++.so.6 (0x00007f112569d000)
    libm.so.6 => /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libm.so.6 (0x00007f1125397000)
    libgcc_s.so.1 => /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libgcc_s.so.1 (0x00007f1125180000)
    libc.so.6 => /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libc.so.6 (0x00007f1124db8000)
    libdl.so.2 => /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libdl.so.2 (0x00007f1124bb4000)
    libdbus-1.so.3 => /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libdbus-1.so.3 (0x00007f112496e000)
    /lib/ld-linux-x86-64.so.2 => /lib64/ld-linux-x86-64.so.2 (0x000055eb18b8b000)
    libpersistence-common-object.so => /home/lib/libpersistence-common-object.so (0x00007f1124763000)
    librt.so.1 => /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/librt.so.1 (0x00007f112455a000)
    libpal_core.so => /home/lib/libpal_core.so (0x00007f1124327000)
    libtools_common.so => /home/lib/libtools_common.so (0x00007f112407b000)
    libparsercreator.so => /home/lib/libparsercreator.so (0x00007f1123e70000)
    libsac_64.so => /home/lib/libsac_64.so (0x00007f1123c6d000)
    libwicomeconnectionapi.so => /home/lib/libwicomeconnectionapi.so (0x00007f1123a6a000)
    libpersistence-comObj-sqliteDB.so => /home/lib/libpersistence-comObj-sqliteDB.so (0x00007f112385d000)
    libsqlite3.so.0 => /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libsqlite3.so.0 (0x00007f11235a4000)
```

---

```
$ ./<Binary name>
bash: No such file or directory
```

---

```
$bash ./<Binary name>
./<Binary name>: ./<Binary name>: cannot execute binary file
```

---

**Query :** Executable Permission is set to the binary, the binary exists in the directory I am trying to execute. Please advise us what could be the possible reason for this error

Comment: Are you in the said directory or outside it?

Comment: Is the filesystem where the executable file is located perhaps marked noexe?  That will prevent any execution, regardless of permissions.

Answer (score 0):

Please note that the two ways to execute are:

1. If executing from same folder as binary file use:

   ```
   ./<binary_file_name>
   ```
2. If executing from outside the location of the binary file use:

   ```
    /path/to/binary/<binary_file_name>
   ```